# How to check whether a user has records in past?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Sample Table**

```
================================================================
id | user_id  | certificate_id  | is_retraining  | created_on
================================================================
1  | 1        |   1             | false          |  2021-01-01 
2  | 1        |   2             | false          |  2021-01-02 
3  | 2        |   1             | false          |  2021-01-03 
4  | 2        |   2             | false          |  2021-03-03 
5  | 3        |   1             | true           |  2021-10-10 
6  | 2        |   2             | true           |  2021-10-10
```

Above sample table consists `Users info who completed certifications`. An user can also go for retraining but he/she should have completed a course before retaking it.

`User Id: 2` is retrained on `certificate 2`, he has a record in past (Completed same certificate earlier), but
`User id: 3` has no certificates in past but he directly choose retraining.

How can we identify users who went for retraining without having a certification (Particular certificate) in past?

Ideally im looking for below structure for all retrainings?

```
=============================================
user_id  | certificate_id  | has_past_records
==============================================
2        |   2             | true
3        |   1             | false
```

Comment: Data in SQL is inherently ***un-ordered***.  Without a timestamp (or other indicator of order), none of those records are 'past-records' or 'current-records'.  Are there any other columns that can be used to indicate which order the rows happened in?

Comment: @MatBailie yes in my db table there is a timestamp. i will update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `LAG()` to find out the previous record's value.

If the previous record doesn't exist, `LAG()` will return `NULL` by default.

So, the following code identifies three possibilities...

1. Has never trained before
2. Is re-training following a previous re-training
3. Is re-training following a previous initial-training

```
WITH
  history AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    LAG(is_retraining) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, certificate_id
                                 ORDER BY created_on
                            )
                              AS previous_training_status
  FROM
    your_table
)
SELECT
  user_id,
  certificate_id,
  CASE
    WHEN previous_training_status IS NULL THEN 'never_previously_trained'
    WHEN previous_training_status = true  THEN 'previously_retrained'
                                          ELSE 'previously_trained'
  END
FROM
  history
WHERE
  is_retraining = true
```